# Convert "m/d/y" date from a form text input field to a mysql datetime "friendly" input?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

So I have a problem. Trying to convert input from form text input field which is in the following format: 08/06/2013 to a value that can be inserted into mysql datetime column.

I have tried this

```
$startdate_timestamp = strtotime($this->startdate); 
// $this->startdate is the value from the input field
$this->startdate = date("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",$startdate_timestamp);
```

But it seems that it is not doing anything. Is there any other way than this that would work ? I am using Yii framework so that is why code looks weird :)

Comment: First of all, if you read the formatting structures for the `date` command, you'll see that **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** is not a valid output format.

Comment: You are correct :) It started working with your date format replacement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$this->startdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->startdate));
```

This will put it in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format compatible with MYSQL.

Comment: This code looks exactly the same as mine, just put on one line :)

Comment: Hardly... I used the correct formatting structures `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Answer (score 5):

`strtotime()` is smart, but it's not psychic or a genius, and when it screws up, it screws up bigtime. Don't use it, especially with ambiguous formats like `m/d/y`. There's no guarantee it won't be treated as as `d/m/y`.

Use [date_create_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead, which lets you explicitly specify the input format. This is far more reliable, since you'll be in control over how the `d` and `m` portions are handled:

```
$ts = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '08/06/2013');
$start_date = $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Note that `date_create_from_format` returns a `DateTime` object, not a *timestamp*.

Comment: Your comment is very useful as well as DevlshOnes, so I dont know which one to pick as a solution :)

Comment: Which also means that the second line: `$this->startdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $startdate_timestamp);` will **FAIL** because the `date()` command only accepts a *timestamp*. So, those of you that upvoted this answer weren't paying very good attention.

Comment: @Novica89 Have you tried using this line of code as a replacement for your first line of code? That will tell you which answer to accept.

Comment: Havent tried using the datetime object yet, but I am sure it does work too. I have used Devils quick fix for the date format and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Do it on insertion using MySQL query superpowers. PHP date functions are a PITA: INSERT INTO FOO (date_field) values (DATE_FORMAT($this->startdate, '%Y %M %D')); Hope that helps!

Comment: Since I am using Yii, he takes care of the queries from form, i need to process it before saving the form :)

Comment: Got it. Do this then, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#formatDateTime